# MongoDb: $inc multiple documents with unique index

Tags: mongodb

I have the following code:

```
db.foo.insert([{_pos:1,b:12},{_pos:2,a:23},{_pos:3,c:12}])
db.foo.createIndex( { "_pos" : 1 }, { unique:  true } )
db.foo.update({}, { "$inc" : {"_pos" : 1} }, { multi : true })
```

The last line gives me the following error:

> E11000 duplicate key error index: JsonTableTemp.foo.$_pos_1 dup key: {
>   : 2.0 }

Adding `$isolated` to the query doesn't help.

How can I increment the `_pos` field without dropping the index first?

I use mongodb 3.2.6

Comment: I just tried this and the createIndex threw the error for me.  The update actually worked perfectly when I removed the { unique: true } from the second line.

Comment: @dyouberg: Why did createIndex fail? Which mongodb version are you using?

Comment: Mongo Version 3.2.0

> db.foo.createIndex( { "_pos" : 1 }, { unique:  true } )
{
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.foo index: _pos_1 dup key: { : 1.0 }",
 "code" : 11000
}

Comment: How is that possible? Are you sure your collection is emtpy and does really only contain 3 documents?

Comment: Hmm you're right, I think I copy pasted the first line twice.  I had 6 entries.

I just tried it again and got the same results you did.  Let me take a better look.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Golyo nope. MongoDb is simply not built for such operations

Answer (score 3):

Ok I got it...

Since you are making the indexes unique - the values cannot ever share the same value.  The values are [1,2,3].  The [increment](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) is an atomic operation by MongoDB so they occur one at a time... First would be [2,2,3] then [2,3,3] then finally [2,3,4].

To prove this... simply reverse the values to [3,2,1] to begin.

```
> db.foo5.insert([{_pos:3,b:12},{_pos:2,a:23},{_pos:1,c:12}])
BulkWriteResult({
    "writeErrors" : [ ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 3,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
})
> db.foo5.createIndex( { "_pos" : 1 }, { unique:  true } )
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.foo5.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a9f76cb28f053d25a821a5"), "_pos" : 3, "b" : 12 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a9f76cb28f053d25a821a6"), "_pos" : 2, "a" : 23 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a9f76cb28f053d25a821a7"), "_pos" : 1, "c" : 12 }
> db.foo5.update({}, { "$inc" : {"_pos" : 1} }, { multi : true })
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 3, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 3 })
> db.foo5.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a9f76cb28f053d25a821a5"), "_pos" : 4, "b" : 12 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a9f76cb28f053d25a821a6"), "_pos" : 3, "a" : 23 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a9f76cb28f053d25a821a7"), "_pos" : 2, "c" : 12 }
```

Comment: Yes I found that out as well, but changing the order is not really an option for me. That's why I asked: How can I increment the _pos field **without** dropping the index first?

Comment: Yeah it looks like either the unique part of the index would have to be removed, or some form of concurrency control needs to apply to the operation.  I tried the $isolated as well and couldn't get that to work.  

Is there a reason your index needs to be unique?

Comment: If I remove the unique part, I have to ensure the uniqueness client-side, which feels wrong. Also I think a unique index will speed up some operations, compared to a normal index.

Comment: Then we either need to find a way to perform the increment in a non-atomic fashion, or we need to pre-sort the data in descending order before calling the update.  Both of these would add overhead also.  I tried findAndModify and $isolated but neither of them worked.  $isolated just works at the document level and locks the document from a second operation so I don't think it is applicable here.